# Add a dictionary to list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have this list:

```
[
  {'shop': 2, 'products': [{'title': 'My Product'}]}, 
  {'shop': 1, 'products': [{'title': 'My awesome Product'}]}
]
```

Now, I want to add where shop=1 another dictionary to products list. (Shop value is an unique value)

What I want to get is this:

```
{'shop': 1, 'products': [{'title': 'My awesome Product'},{'title': 'My NEW Product'}]}
```

Any idea?

Comment: ' My NEW Product' is another product that I want to add to the list produtcs

Comment: just create the dict and append it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming outerlist is the over all container of list of dictionaries and newproduct is your new product:

```
for i in range(len(outerlist)):
    if outerlist[i]['shop'] == 1:
        outerlist[i]['products'].append(newproduct)
        break
```

You can append anything to a list which includes some value like a string/int, another list, a set, or even a dictionary. Actually adding it to the appropriate shop just requires looping through the big list till you find the right element, after which break from the loop as shops is a unique number.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough with my question before, but you have been the only one who has understood my question and you gave me the correct answer. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can slice to modify the values of the keys like this:

Assuming that the name of the dictionary is `mydict`:

```
mydict['products'] = []
mydict['products'].append({'title': "My Awesome Product"}, {'title': "My Product"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just append the new title dictionary to the value:

```
your_list[1]['products'].append({'title': 'My NEW Product'})
```